# Error on loading my custom minor mode

Tags: require

I created a custom minor mode for my Wordpress projects:

```
(define-minor-mode wordpress-mode
  "Wordpress minor mode"
  :lighter " Wordpress")

(provide 'wordpress-mode)
```

And on my `init.el` I load the package, associate the minor mode to the major mode `web-mode` and enable yasnippets for this extra minor mode.

```
;; ---- Wordpress Custom Minor Mode --------
;; Loads Wordpress Custom Minor Mode Manually
(use-package wordpress
  :load-path ("~/.emacs.d/elpa-offline/wordpress")

  :init
  ;; Turn on `Wordpress mode and snippets when web-mode on.
  (add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda ()
                 (wordpress-mode 1)
                 (yas-activate-extra-mode 'wordpress-mode )
                 )
        )

 )
```

Just to clarify, everything works fine, but everytime I open Emacs I get an error:

```
Error (use-package): wordpress/:catch: Required feature ‘wordpress’ was not provide
```

I tried removing the lambda function and leaving just the `load-path` and enabling the minor mode by hand with `M-x wordpress-mode`. I still get the same error on Emacs opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(provide 'wordpress-mode)` provides a feature named `wordpress-mode` and your `use-package` config clearly wants to `(require 'wordpress)` and is, naturally, failing to do so.

Check the `use-package` documentation -- I'm sure there's a simple way to specify that the feature symbol name and the library name are not the same.  Without `use-package`, this would be: `(require 'wordpress-mode "wordpress")`

Or just `(provide 'wordpress)` instead -- it's your library, after all, so you can call the feature whatever you want to.

Comment: `(provide 'wordpress)` did the trick, now I got no error or warning. Thank you